# RSS parsing output in XML format in php

Tags: php, rss

Problem. After parsing RSS in PHP i need to return content in XML format but it's showing as the HTML i tried with sending headers but without any success.

Any ideas

```
<?php
            echo'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';   
            echo'<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">';  
            $rss = new DOMDocument();
                $rss->load('url_adress');
                $feed = array();
                foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                $item = array ('title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'desc' => $nod>getElementsByTagNameNS("url_adress","description")->item(0)->nodeValue,);
                 array_push($feed, $item);
                    }
                    $limit = 5;
                    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                                    echo '<item>';
                                    $desc = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                                    echo '</item>';
                    }
                    echo '</channel>';
    ?>
```

Comment: There's no `</xml>` tag ever. And `<channel>` is opened nowhere. Why should it be closed?

Comment: there is closing for xml and chanel in last line 'echo '</channel></xml>';'

Comment: First - have you ever seen xml file? Have you ever seen `</xml>` there? Second - you __don't__ open `channel` tag anywhere. So why do you close it?

Comment: OK corrected but still not to helpful output is html and need xml I know its some basic problem but still dunno how to fix this